# PowerShell - Merge CSVs

Tags: windows, powershell, csv, merge

I created a script which gets `Name`, `CreationTime` and `Duration` from each .mp4 file in a specific directory and than exports the data into a CSV file using the Cmdlet `Export-Csv`.

Now I have 3 CSV exports and I want to merge them, so I tried this:

```
$Data = @()
$CSVsPaths | ForEach-Object {
    $Data += Import-Csv -Path "$_" -Encoding "UTF8"
}
$Data
```

But for some reason, some of the objects are duplicated, and I'm sure the exports all contains different data. What am I doing wrong?

---

*Edit:*

Here are the CSVs: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1MbeUenLxbKdlle6rKFwc3jJNZf85AMtd

Comment: Show us the input data and the duplicates :)

Comment: By duplicated you mean all values in the `Name` column should be different? also, `$data = Get-ChildItem -Filter *.csv | Import-Csv -Encoding UTF8` should be a cleaner approach

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon By duplicated I mean the whole Psobject with its "Name", "CreationTime" and "Duration" properties in the Array. Anyways, thank you very much for the tip

Comment: Your code will merge all CSVs into one array of objects but doesn't ensure there will not be duplicates, some CSVs may have the same entries, have you ensured all CSVs have unique rows or are you looking for a code that will ensure this? It's not actually clear

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I am sure that all the CSV files have different entries, and my goal is to merge the CSVs. Sorry if I'm not clear enough

Comment: @Dstr0 There are exactly 86 duplicates in the final output because there are exactly 86 duplicates between the Export 2 and Export 3 files. Do you want to only output unique rows across all 3 files?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes, that's what I need. Anyways, I was SURE there weren't duplicates, but I was wrong... I'm really sorry, I wasted your time...

Comment: If you want to see for yourself, the duplicated values per Column: `$data[0].PSObject.Properties.Name | % { ($data | Group-Object $_ | ? Count -GT 1).Count }` this gives me 86 for the first column, 107 for the second and 152 for the third

Comment: If you want to get rid of duplicates in 1 or all columns you can give [this function](https://gist.github.com/santysq/113663febed54084e241476c9121a5dc#file-filter-unique-ps1) a try, you would use like: `$data = Get-ChildItem -Filter *.csv | Import-Csv -Encoding UTF8 | Filter-Unique -On *`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your output has duplicate rows because *duplicates already exist in your data set*.

To locate the duplicated rows, use `Get-Content` against the input files - the file system provider will attach some hidden properties to the output that we can use to identify the duplicate location(s) later:

```
# find all non-unique strings in the input files
$nonUniques = Get-Content '.\Export*.csv' |Group-Object |Where-Object Count -gt 1 |ForEach-Object Group 

# use the PSChildName and ReadCount provider properties to identify the files that host the duplicate content,
# then use Format-Table to show output nicely grouped on the non-unique string value
$nonUniques |Select @{Name='Name';Expression='PSChildName'},@{Name='Line';Expression='ReadCount'},@{Name='Duplicate';Expression={$_}} |Format-Table Name,Line -GroupBy Duplicate
```

Which, given the input data you linked, will produce something like this:

```
   Duplicate: "QVR_06082021_141022 (PRIMA VOLTA CHE REGISTRO).mp4","06/08/2021 14:10:22","00:00:46"

Name                                      Line
----                                      ----
Export 2 (da 24-06-2022 a 31-07-2022).csv  113
Export 3 (da 06-08-2021 a 31-08-2021).csv    3


   Duplicate: "QVR_06082021_142308.mp4","06/08/2021 14:23:08","00:00:50"

Name                                      Line
----                                      ----
Export 2 (da 24-06-2022 a 31-07-2022).csv  114
Export 3 (da 06-08-2021 a 31-08-2021).csv    4


   Duplicate: "VID_20210806_220220.mp4","06/08/2021 22:02:20","00:00:20"

Name                                      Line
----                                      ----
Export 2 (da 24-06-2022 a 31-07-2022).csv  115
Export 3 (da 06-08-2021 a 31-08-2021).csv    5
```

Comment: I'm sorry for wasing your time man